# Why does the robot run continually? Is it stuck in a loop?

Tags: java, robotics

I set the FTC robot to drive forward 100 ticks using encoders, but it drives continuously until opmode is stopped. Adjusting the speed in the code doesn't seem to work either, and it's stuck at the same speed.

This is our code:

```
package org.firstinspires.ftc.teamcode.drive.auto;

import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.Autonomous;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.eventloop.opmode.LinearOpMode;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotor;
import com.qualcomm.robotcore.hardware.DcMotorSimple;


@Autonomous(name="encoderAutoRB", group="Autonomous")
public class encoderAutoRB extends LinearOpMode {

    private DcMotor left;
    private DcMotor right;


    private int leftPos;
    private int rightPos;

    @Override
    public void runOpMode() {
        left = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "frontLeftMotor");
        left = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "backLeftMotor");

        right = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "frontRightMotor");
        right = hardwareMap.get(DcMotor.class, "backRightMotor");

        left.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.STOP_AND_RESET_ENCODER);
        right.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.STOP_AND_RESET_ENCODER);

        right.setDirection(DcMotorSimple.Direction.REVERSE);

        leftPos = 0;
        rightPos = 0;

        waitForStart();

        move(100, 100, 0.5);
    }
    private void move(int leftTarget, int rightTarget, double speed) {
        leftPos += leftTarget;
        rightPos += rightTarget;

        left.setTargetPosition(leftPos);
        right.setTargetPosition(rightPos);

        left.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);
        right.setMode(DcMotor.RunMode.RUN_TO_POSITION);

        left.setPower(speed);
        right.setPower(speed);

        while (opModeIsActive() && left.isBusy() && right.isBusy()) {
            idle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What code is in `waitForStart()`? What if it isn't waiting?

Answer (score 2):

1. Your encoder is not plugged in or is plugged into the wrong motor port
2. Your encoder is plugged in backwards (if using a level shifter)
3. The motor power wires are swapped (usually done as a "quick fix" to spin the motor the opposite direction instead of changing software, which doesn't work when using encoders)

Add a telemetry line to your while loop to print the "getPosition()" values for each motor as a way to verify proper encoder operation.